# Google Chrome form onChange not firing

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

How do I get Google Chrome (9.0.597.98 on Windows 7 64-bit) to fire a form's onchange? If you play around with the following example, nothing gets consoled out. It's working fine in Firefox 3.6.13.

```
<form onchange="console.info('form changed')">
 <select>
  <option>uno</option>
  <option>dos</option>
 </select>
 <input type="radio" name="videoDevice" value="tres" checked="checked" />
 <input type="radio" name="videoDevice" value="cuatro" checked="checked" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Binding the `change` event via JS seems to work ok:

**HTML**

```
<form id="test">
 <select>
  <option>uno</option>
  <option>dos</option>
 </select>
 <input type="radio" name="videoDevice" value="tres" checked="checked" />
 <input type="radio" name="videoDevice" value="cuatro" checked="checked" />
</form>
```

**JS**

```
document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('change', function() {
    alert('change fired');
}, false);
```

Comment: So again we come to the subject of coding style. By putting the change listener in the HTML, someone else reading my code can quickly see what's going on. By attaching the listener with JS, the listener is, in essence, invisible. They'd have to read through all my JS code logic to find out what part of my code is handling the onchange.

Comment: Technically, separating logic from presentation is the preferred way to do it. But that aside, you can always document - in both the HTML and the JS - what's going on. I tend to put all my listeners right at the beginning of my `$(document).ready()` (or whatever the equivalent is in your preferred framework) so that it's clearly visible what's bound to what. Also, this method works and the `onchange="..."` doesn't for some unknown reason ;)

Comment: I guess you're right. But JS is hairy in terms of how it fits into Model-View-Controller. It's both a view and controller. It can create animations (view), process user input (control), and store data for complex applications (model).

Comment: Damn, man. Firefox needs to get a monopoly on the browser wars. Then we'd be developing websites faster than ever.

Comment: Agreed that JS crosses a lot of boundaries. But HTML doesn't - it's presentation only. Adding logic (even if it's just a function call) oversteps its bounds. Obviously there are exceptions to the rules, but the more you can keep HTML purely presentational the easier it is when you're working on a team with a designer that **only** does HTML/CSS.

Comment: Man, IE8 doesn't trigger onChange with the JS solution.

Comment: Try using a framework to do the binding. IE might require a different syntax that the framework should handle for you. **Edit**: Ya, IE: `document.getElementById('test').attachEvent('onchange', function() {...});` (I think - stupid IE).

Comment: I'm using Prototype's `$('formId').observe('change', function(){alert('changed');});`.

Answer (score 1):

Basically the form has only the following two events: onreset,onsubmit.
You can do a workaround:

```
window.onload=(function ()
{
    var Form=
    {
        w3c: !!window.addEventListener,
        addEvent: function (form,type,listener)
        {
            var inputs=form.elements;
            for (var i=0,l=inputs.length; i<l; ++i)
            {
                var input=inputs[i];
                if (this.w3c)
                {
                    input.addEventListener(type,listener,false);
                }
                else
                {
                    input.attachEvent("on"+type,listener);
                }
            }
        },
        fixEvents: function (form)
        {
            var eventPattern=/^on(\w+)$/;
            var attribute;
            for (var i=0,l=form.attributes.length; i<l; ++i)
            {
                var attribute=form.attributes.item(i);
                var name=attribute.name;
                var value=attribute.value;
                if (eventPattern.test(name) && !form[name])
                {
                    var type=eventPattern.exec(name)[1];
                    var listener=new Function(value);
                    this.addEvent(form,type,listener);
                }
            }
        }
    };

    return function ()
    {
        var forms=document.getElementsByTagName("form");
        for (var i=0,l=forms.length; i<l; ++i)
        {
            Form.fixEvents(forms[i]);
        }
    };
})();
```

Comment: Why does Firefox have the complete set of events and Chrome doesn't?

Answer (score 1):

```
     var button = document.form.adet;
        if (button.addEventListener) {  // all browsers except IE before version 9
            button.addEventListener ("change", function () { alert('1'); }, false);
        }
        else {
            if (button.attachEvent) {   // IE before version 9
                button.attachEvent ("onchange", function () { alert('2'); });
            }
        }
```